# Javascript filter and get multiple indices

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is there a way in javascript to filter and get the indices of all the found items.
Example:

```
filter([{a: 5},{a,9},{a:1},{a:2}], el => el.a<3)  ===>>>  [2,3]
```

I have a feeling underscore should have this utility but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Drawing on all the comments, with ES6 conciseness:
`let findFilterIndices = (items, f) => items.map( (e,i) => f(e) ? i : null ).filter(e=>e);`

And now we can just do: `findFilterIndices( [{a: 5},{a: 9},{a:1},{a:2}], a => a.a<3 )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use Underscore.js, just simply map the indices and filter in pure JavaScript. I wrote a function below to handle the map-filter logic. Just add your own filter.

```js
function findFilteredIndicies(arr, filterFn) {
  return arr.map(function(item, index) {
    return filterFn.apply(null, arguments) ? index : -1;
  }).filter(function(index) {
    return index > -1;
  });
}

var items = [{ a: 5 }, { a: 9 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }];


var indicies = findFilteredIndicies(items, function(item) {
  return item.a < 3;
});


document.body.innerHTML = indicies;
```

---

## Another Way...

You could also use `Array.prototype.reduce`, which would be more concise, because it essentially combines map-filter.

### Debug Form

```
function findFilteredIndicies(arr, filterFn) {
  return arr.reduce(function(result, item, index) {
    if (filterFn.apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments, 1))) {
      result.push(index);
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
}
```

### Minimal Form

```
function findFilteredIndicies(a, f) {
  return a.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
    return f.apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments, 1)) ? r.concat(i) : r;
  }, []);
}
```

### Minified Form

```
findFilteredIndicies=function(a,f){return a.reduce(function(r,e,i){return f.apply(null,[].slice.call(arguments,1))?r.concat(i):r;},[]);}
```

Comment: @user2964554, With indices, you should be returning `-1` for non-matching indices. This is the case with many frameworks and even native JavaScript libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine map and filter:

```
_.filter(_.map([{a: 5},{a: 9},{a:1},{a:2}], function(e, i) { return e.a < 3 ? i : null; }), function(e) {return e;})
```

Comment: Or you can do it without underscore:
    [{a: 5},{a: 9},{a:1},{a:2}].map(function(e, i) { return e.a < 3 ? i : null }).filter(function(e) { return e})

Answer (score 0):

Small solution for a small problem.

```js
var data = [{ a: 5 }, { a: 9 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }],
    indices = [];

data.forEach(function (a, i) {
    a.a < 3 && indices.push(i);
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(indices, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clean solution using Typescript and ES6:

```
function findFilterIndices<T>(items: T[], predicate: (value: T) => boolean): number[] {
    return items
        .map((value, index) => predicate(value) ? index : null)
        .filter(index => index != null) as number[]
}
```

It can be used as follows:

```
const arr = [11, 8, 17, 4]
console.log(findFilterIndices(arr, value => value > 10)) // prints [0, 2]
```